# Typescript error with `T extends [Type]` but not with `[Type]` directly

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to reorganize some fields in a TypeScript type, but I've hit a roadblock with an error. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
interface Test {
    data: string;
    where: string;
}

type TTA<T extends Test> = Pick<Omit<T, "data">, "where">;
```

I get an error that says: `Type '"where"' does not satisfy the constraint '"data" | Exclude<keyof T, "data">'.ts(2344)`. However, it works fine if I use it this way:

```
type TTB = Pick<Omit<Test, "data">, "where">;
```

Could someone assist me in resolving this error and explaining why the first approach doesn't function as expected?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=46&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyyAJnGHAFzJZSgDmA3IcQO4AW0E1tDzBAX0KEwATwAOKVKgCCAHlTIIAD0ggSGNJjAA%20ZAF5kABWAIA1nIDyAW2BgFAGmQAiMhWc6nzjlw-8RElKoAEIGxqYWNnYK2l5ucB5ePlAQfkA)

Comment: What the heck is `OmitFields` meant to do? The result will always be the input object.

Comment: It's a simplified version of my complex code.  Its original purpose was to remove fields from a child type - The `Pick<T, K>`  will perform an additional `Omit` operation within it.

Comment: @Val, what exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's almost certainly because of the generic type parameter, as you showed. [After doing a bit of inlining and simplification](https://tsplay.dev/weyqgw), I get `Type '"where"' does not satisfy the constraint '"data" | Exclude<keyof T, "data">'. (2344)`. Which is definitely satisfied for `Test`, but probably not for something that _extends_ `Test`.

Comment: @Ben, with this, I can automatically perform type checking for RESTful APIs using **typia**. You can view this as an academic discussion, it's still worth exploring.

Comment: Some more experiments: https://tsplay.dev/WYyxzW. Inlining `Pick` and `Omit` changes nothing, but removing the `Pick` part changes `"where"` in the error to `string`.

Comment: However, `extends` says it's okay: https://tsplay.dev/wgBxyW

Comment: @DarrylNoakes, Quote["Which is definitely satisfied for Test, but probably not for something that extends Test"] no, any type that extends 'Test' will always include all the fields of 'Test.' You can't remove fields from a type by extending a class.

Comment: Just hinting that TS can do weird things with generic type parameters. Some optimizations can interfere or go wrong, etc.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes As you can see in your test at `tsplay.dev/wgBxyW`, you'll notice there's a conflict with how TypeScript behaves. In this case, the T type certainly includes the fields 'data' and 'where.' That's why I've raised this question.

Comment: It would probably be useful to trim down your code. The interface can be simplified to `{ data: string, where: string }`. `OmitFields` is not needed, at least for the outer case (it's just the outer `Pick` that has an issue; mention that, that there is no issue with `Omit`; because of the `Exclude` in `Pick`...). Inlining the inner `OmitFields` also shows that it's not an issue because of it being a separate generic. (And makes some tests easier, such as removing the `Pick`.)

Comment: ① Leaving aside the fact that the example doesn't seem to do anything useful, the way to resolve the error is probably `type TT<T extends Test> = OmitFields<T, "data" | "where">`.  I'm assuming this is *not* the main focus of your question, or else you'd present some more functional example.

Comment: ② If the question is "why is this happening", it's because `Omit` is a [conditional type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and `OF<T, "data">` is thus a *generic* conditional type because `T` is a generic type parameter. Generic conditional types are essentially *opaque* to the compiler; it is unable to compute invariants the way humans do (keep in mind that the word "Omit" is suggestive to human beings, not to the compiler).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, you made the point (about how Omit and condition type works). I need some time to organize for a detail question to what I really need. please write as an answer, I'll ask a new question when ready.

Comment: Ah, of course. I forgot about `Exclude` being a conditional, and the behavior of TS with conditionals in the presence of generic type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a design limitation of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#53368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53368)

The problem with

```
type TTA<T extends Test> = Pick<Omit<T, "data">, "where">;
```

is that `Omit<T, "data">` depends on a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T`.  ([The `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is implemented with [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) which is implemented as a conditional type.)  And such types are notoriously difficult for the type checker to analyze.  Generic conditional types are essentially opaque to the compiler; it is unable to compute invariants the way humans do (plus the word `"Omit"` is suggestive to human beings, not to the compiler). So while a human being might reason that for all `T extends Test`, that `Omit<T, "data">` must contain a `where` property because `T` contains a `where` property and `Omit` won't remove it, the compiler just gives up and cannot verify this.

---

Resolving the error is a somewhat subjective matter of deciding how to convince the compiler that the property is acceptable:

```
// like this
type TTB<T extends Test> = Pick<Omit<T, "data"> & { where?: any }, "where">;

// or maybe like this
type LoosePick<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Pick<T, K & keyof T>
type TTC<T extends Test> = LoosePick<Omit<T, "data">, "where">;

// et cetera
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLIAmcYcAXMllKAOYDcByA7gBbQSXV2MC+eeMAE8ADilSoAggB5UyCAA9IIIhjSYwAPmQBeZAAVgCANbSA8gFtgYWQBpkAIhJkHm+w7YdXjAcLFpUACFZeSUIFTV0LG09QxNzKxtUd2c4V2QAMlwWdigIAH5KOBAhZF53TzzvX1EUABkAewaMCDjTZOQAaVDlVQMoBrEoYU6IIRiDI3b7bqzjMYaYNE1BWoCAYRDFXsiNCcbm1qmE6ztHVNcK3IhvIA)